# Multiplication by the array members to get a new array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```js
function cleanPayment() {
  var budget = sheet.getRange(1,6,1,1).getValue();
  var cardsTotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cardsTotal += Number(cards[i]);
    var perCard = budget / cardsTotal;
    var payments = [];
    payments.push(cards[i] * perCard);
  }
Logger.log(payments);
}
```

`payments` should contain an array, isn't it? But `Logger.log(payments)` returns single number. Is smb see mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: aren't you initializing payments each time through the for loop..

Comment: And where do you define cards ?

Comment: Cards defined as global variable outside function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring the `var payments = [];` outside the `for` loop